# Android HTTP Client "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: java, android, json, http, https

I am creating an android application that will upload some data to a database using the following code found below.  I have been able to add other pieces of information to the database (when the api calls for different things), however here I get the following error (code follows).  Thank you in advance!

```
05-27 20:35:51.144: E/content(8749): array(1) {  [0]=>  array(2) {    ["value"]=>    string(5) "18-24"    ["question_id"]=>    string(2) "14"  }}{"success":0,"error":"Query: INSERT INTO client_question_answers (client_form_id, question_id, value) VALUES ('4', '14', '18-24')\nDatabase error message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mypsych`.`client_question_answers`, CONSTRAINT `client_question_answers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`client_form_id`) REFERENCES `client_forms` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)\nDatabase error number: 1452"}
```

Make the call here:

```
NetworkUtility.sendForm("4", "14","18-24", key);
```

Here is the sendForm method:

```
public static void sendForm(String client_form_id, String question_id, String value, String key)  throws ClientProtocolException, JSONException, IOException
{
    List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters=new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();

    JSONObject answers = new JSONObject();

    answers.put("question_id", question_id);
    answers.put("value", value);

    JSONArray answers1 = new JSONArray();
    answers1.put(answers);

    String answers2 = answers1.toString();


    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answers", answers2));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));

    StringBuilder url=new StringBuilder();
    url.append("https://myurl.com/api/forms/answers/create/");
    url.append(client_form_id);

    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(getJSONContent(parameters, url.toString()));
    Log.e("goal", root.toString());

}
```

Finally the method that handles the actual HTTP commands

```
private static String getJSONContent(List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters, String url)  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request=new HttpPost(url);

    if (cookieStore == null) {
        cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    }
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
    request.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse response=client.execute(request, httpContext);
    InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line=null;
    StringBuilder content=new StringBuilder();
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        content.append(line);
    }
    Log.e("content", content.toString());
    return content.toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a foreign key constraint on client_form_id that references the client_forms table.

Your call:

```
NetworkUtility.sendForm("4", "14","18-24", key);
```

Uses a client_form_id (4) that does not exist in the client_forms table.